# Sorting CSV to be written into a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, csv, sorting

I have a CSV file which is converted into a JSON file with a Python script. It works but I want JSON to have the same sorting of CSV file. This is what I've tried without success:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import json

CSV_PATH = './myFile.csv'
JSON_PATH = './myFile.json'

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_PATH, 'r'))

json_list = []
for row in csv_file:
   json_list.append(row)

sortedlist = sorted(json_list, key=lambda row:(row['id']), reverse=False)

file(JSON_PATH, 'w').write(json.dumps(
    sortedlist, sort_keys=False, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '), 
    encoding="utf-8",ensure_ascii=False))
```

My CSV looks like that:

```
id,name,lastname
1,John,Red
2,Steve,Brown
```

But the created JSON looks like that even with that lambda function:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "id": "1",
    "lastname": "Red"
  },
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "id": "2",
    "lastname": "Brown"
  }
]
```

What I'd like to get is "id, "name" and then "lastname".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries don't keep the original order.
You may want to try using `OrderedDict` from `collection` module

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_dictionary=OrderedDict()
my_dictionary['foo']=3
my_dictionary['bar']=1
my_dictionary
OrderedDict([('foo', 3), ('bar', 1)])
```

[An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

It should do the job:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
json.dumps(OrderedDict([("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 2)]))
```

Out: '{"b": 1, "a": 2, "c": 2}'

```
json.dumps({'b': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 2})
```

Out: '{"a": 2, "c": 2, "b": 1}'

If you want to reorder your dict, `Dictreader` takes `fieldnames` as positional argument:

```
FIELDNAMES = ['id', 'name', 'last_name']
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_PATH, 'r'), fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
json_list = []
for row in csv_file:
   # Reorder according to your needs
   data = OrderedDict([
       ('name', row['name']), ('last_name', row['last_name']), ('id', row['id'])])
   json_list.append(data)
   ...
```

Comment: I already knew that, this is why I was asking for a way to sort them.

Comment: @antonioag look at updated post. Just create OrderedDict with reading csv.

Comment: @JeffersonHoup : He already *does* created an `OrderedDict` if he's using Python 3.  That's what `DictReader` returns.

Comment: @antonioag There updated ver of answer. With OrderedDict you can make json with any order what you want.

Comment: OMG it works! Thanks! Am I wrong or it also saves in JSON file the field names associated as first "entry" and then my data? Is there something to avoid it?

Comment: One line above `for row in csv_file:` add `next(csv_file)`, should work tho, also remember to accept the answer if that solves your problem.

Comment: @Pythonist: you don't need to specify the field names for `DictReader`, they will be taken from the first line of the CSV file. So, if you omit the `fieldnames=` argument when creating the reader you do not need to explicitly skip the first row.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` is sorting the entries in the list.  So if your original list was :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "id": "2",
    "surname": "Brown"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "id": "1",
    "surname": "Red"
  }
]
```

It would put it in the correct order.  As it is, your list is *already* in the same order as the CSV files.  Your problem is that each entry in the list is a dict, and dictionaries don't preserve the order of their elements.

Comment: As an aside, if this is a *real* project, go read http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Bad practice with "you are in luck". Do not use sorting like that. Be sure your dict will be right with any changes in the future.

Comment: @JeffersonHoup How would you do that?

Comment: I wish I were in luck but unfortunately I'm planning to update my CSV with other values which can't be alphabetically sorted.

Comment: @antonioag : I suggest changing your example to "lastname" then.  That keeps it simple, and makes your desired order non-alphabetic.

Comment: @MartinBonner json.dumps(OrderedDict([("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 2)])) in that style

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, I fixed my example. I didn't realize that in that way could have been alphabetically ordered.

Comment: @JeffersonHoup: a) I don't see how that is any different from sorted_keys=True (it relies on alphabetical ordering of the keys); b) it doesn't explain how to read something like that from CSV.

Comment: @MartinBonner a) sorted_keys=True = alphabetical sort. ~ 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2; json.dumps(OrderedDict....) = sort in real keys order ~ 'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to maintain the order of the keys:

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

CSV_PATH = 'myFile.csv'
JSON_PATH = 'myFile.json'

with open(CSV_PATH) as csv_file, open(JSON_PATH, 'w') as json_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    data = [OrderedDict((field, row[field]) for field in reader.fieldnames) for row in reader]
    json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '), encoding="utf-8",ensure_ascii=False)
```

Output for your input CSV file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Red"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Steve",
    "surname": "Brown"
  }
]
```

This code iterates over the rows of the CSV file and creates a list of `OrderedDict`s. The order of the keys is maintained by the `fieldnames` list of the `DictReader` object.

The list is then output directly to file using [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) in preference to `json.dumps()` because it's slightly easier to do so.